# Access to object property insed an arary on twig

Tags: php, doctrine, twig

The template has this data(the result of `{{ dump(extra) }}`)

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(MyProject\Entity\Translation)[210]
      private 'language' => 
        object(Proxies\__CG__\MyProject\Entity\Language)[225]
          public '__initializer__' => null
          public '__cloner__' => null
          public '__isInitialized__' => boolean true
          private 'code' (MyProject\Entity\Language) => string 'es' (length=2)
          private 'id' (MyProject\Entity\Language) => int 70
      private 'entity' => string 'Reason' (length=6)
      private 'entityId' => int 10000
      private 'field' => string 'text' (length=4)
      private 'text' => string 'No quiero recibir emails' (length=24)
  1 => 
    object(MyProject\Entity\Translation)[224]
      private 'language' => 
        object(Proxies\__CG__\MyProject\Entity\Language)[225]
          public '__initializer__' => null
          public '__cloner__' => null
          public '__isInitialized__' => boolean true
          private 'code' (MyProject\Entity\Language) => string 'es' (length=2)
          private 'id' (MyProject\Entity\Language) => int 70
      private 'entity' => string 'Reason' (length=6)
      private 'entityId' => int 10001
      private 'field' => string 'text' (length=4)
      private 'text' => string 'No me gusta la web' (length=18)
  2 => 
    object(MyProject\Entity\Translation)[223]
      private 'language' => 
        object(Proxies\__CG__\MyProject\Entity\Language)[225]
          public '__initializer__' => null
          public '__cloner__' => null
          public '__isInitialized__' => boolean true
          private 'code' (MyProject\Entity\Language) => string 'es' (length=2)
          private 'id' (MyProject\Entity\Language) => int 70
      private 'entity' => string 'Reason' (length=6)
      private 'entityId' => int 10002
      private 'field' => string 'text' (length=4)
      private 'text' => string 'No tengo ningún motivo' (length=23)
  3 => 
    object(MyProject\Entity\Translation)[221]
      private 'language' => 
        object(Proxies\__CG__\MyProject\Entity\Language)[225]
          public '__initializer__' => null
          public '__cloner__' => null
          public '__isInitialized__' => boolean true
          private 'code' (MyProject\Entity\Language) => string 'es' (length=2)
          private 'id' (MyProject\Entity\Language) => int 70
      private 'entity' => string 'Reason' (length=6)
      private 'entityId' => int 10003
      private 'field' => string 'text' (length=4)
      private 'text' => string 'Otros' (length=5)
```

But I'm trying to access to the object properties  but the options in the select are not printed.

```
{{ dump(extra) }}
<select id="motivos_baja" name="motivos_baja" class="form-control">
      <option value="0" selected>Seleccione un motivo</option>
            {% for extra in reason%}
             <option value="{{ reason.getEntityId() }}">{{ reason.getText() }}</option>
             {% endfor %}    
 </select>
```

The objects are `doctrine` entities.

Comment: it's `{{ reason.entityId }}` and `{{ reason.text }}`

Comment: I already tried this way and it doesn't work

Comment: You miss a space in `{% for extra in reason%}`

Comment: @gogaz - This does not matter. Twig is able to resolve this on its own. Meaning if the property is public `twig` will use access to the property directly otherwise it will try to use the `getter` for the property

Comment: @MickaelLeger This is incorrect as well. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/klp8jo), spacing does not matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must fix the loop; in Twig, the for loop works as `for item in list`:

```
{% for reason in extra %}
    {# ... #}
{% endfor %}
```

Second, it looks like the actual reason is a property of the `MyProject\Entity\Translation` object. I assume there is some getter for the entity, therefore you would access the reason text with:

```
{{ reason.getEntity().getText() }}
```

Comment: Your 2nd statement is wrong. The collection `extra` contains objects of the type `Translation` which has a direct property `text`

Comment: `{{ reason.getEntity().getText() }}` its not nedded works with `{{ reason.text }}`

Comment: @DarkBee: Yes, but it’s a private property. Besides, as it is on the `Translation` entity, it is not safe to assume that a `getText` getter on this object would return the text of the `Reason` child entity (which it apparently does, according to @afsdi3.) Therefore, my statement is not wrong; however in this case, there’s a shortcut.

Comment: @lxg if the property is private `twig` will automatically use the `getter` if present and otherwise throw an error the `getter` is non-existing - also `reason` does have a property `entity` but it's a string, so calling `getText` would result in the error `calling getText on non-object`

Comment: @DarkBee: You’re right, the `entity` property is a string … I didn’t expect this and oversaw it.